# geometry options problem

Tags: margins, double-sided, geometry

I am using geometry package with `\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}`. But when I use `geometry`, the options for `left,right,top,bottom` are effecting only in `even` pages not in `odd` pages.

How can i change globally in `geometry` package.

the Class file:

```
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
left={15mm},
right={15mm},
top={15mm},
bottom={15mm},
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Use also `oneside` option when loading `article`.

Comment: I have tried with oneside option. but there is no required output.

Comment: What version of [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) are you using? CTAN puts the most recent one at `5.6`. To see this, add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and look at the contents of your `.log` file *after* `*File List*`. It may be that your version is outdated, since I obtain the expected (equivalent) output for even/odd pages on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

The following example shows that everything is as expected:

### `19551.cls`

```
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}

\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{
left={15mm},
right={15mm},
top={15mm},
bottom={15mm},
}
```

### `19551.tex`

```
\documentclass{19551}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

### The first two pages side by side

[image]